# Drawable icons for app

Tags: android-studio, icons, size

Recently, I've been working for some theming project for Android launchers. I need some guidance and advice from the people around here that could help me with this.

I have created one sample icon for Opera mobile with the size of 192x192. The question is, if I made that icon size as mentioned, should I create another size for it, e.g. 128x128? I'm a bit confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understand your question. If you add a drawable resource to Android Studio, it automatically resizes it to multiple sizes. If you have created one, that will be resized automatically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what i mean here is what is the actual size of icons that i should created for application drawer

Comment: Okay, https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html
Scroll down to the size and format section. 
Basically, for 'Extra-extra-extra-high density screen' it needs to be 192x 192 px

Answer (score 0):

If you want to design icons for android, you better design some for different resolutions. You have to make an icon for each. See at this article https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview. There are the different densities and the multiplication factors.